# Splitting the big JSON file to multiple small JSON file based on the JSON field

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a gzip JSON file which has complex JSON structure and it is multiline false.
It has about 5 million records and each record is a JSON of itself.
I have a field called event.event_name in the JSON and I want to split my big file based on event.event_name and post the split files on to S3.
I want one file for each event.event_name.
I tried reading the big file by

```
textRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(file_path)
```

and it reads the file veryfast in 4 seconds and then I split by

```
filteredRDD = textRDD.filter(lambda line: f'"event_name":"{event_name}"' in line)
```

where it takes 150 seconds and then I load the JSON using

```
df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "false").json(filteredRDD)
```

and it takes 150 seconds.
But when I directly read using

```
df_raw = spark.read.option("multiLine", "false").json(file_paths)
```

it takes 500 seconds and then I filter using

```
df = df_raw.filter(df_raw["event.event_name"] == event_name)
```

and it takes 30 seconds.
I am running this on AWS GLUE with 2 DPUs (4 core 16 GB ram for each DPU) and spark 3.3
Is there a faster way to read and group it by event.event_name and process them faster.
I even flatten the JSON before writing it back as CSV

```
def flatten_json(df, schema, prefix=""):
    flat_cols = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        field_name = prefix + field.name
        field_type = field.dataType
        if isinstance(field_type, StructType):
            nested_cols = flatten_json(df, field_type, field_name + ".")
            flat_cols.extend(nested_cols)
        else:
            flat_cols.append(col(prefix + field.name).alias(field_name.replace(".", "_")))
    return flat_cols
```

then using the flat_cols I will select the fields from df like

```
selected_df = df.select(*flattened_cols)
```

Flattening the cols takes me 180 seconds and selecting is taking me 100 seconds for each event.event_name

Is there an easy way to convert the JSON to CSV or flat file like structure?
My file is gzip and it has 5 million records.

```
The structure of JSON is 
{"app_name":"Foundation","export_hour":"13","export_doc_id":"65b387a65ed33a5","db_name":"Foundation","event":{"uid":"KrPVghgdR3=yjuW5byt2","event_type":"CAMPAIGN_EVENT","event_code":"NOTIFY","push_id":"dK-GiF-kbknW:APA90ISVz9ws3tLJPgC0W0uJs_-56Sa64Hxt2_pIioCVTyv7uk7dYhjTieAc3gGS2CgsBCdg4","event_name":"Received","user_attributes":{"subscription-status":"CANCELLED","guided_session_time":"4:30","completion_flag":true,"unsubscribe":false,"id":"KrPVghgdR3fuKPCyjuW5byt2","no_of_sessions":305,"Daily Mystic Quote":true,"renewal-type":"NA","last_known_country":"India","New Podcasts":true,"ex_currency":"INR","BSP_flag":true,"md_no_of_day_missed":40,"monthly_satsang_language":"Tam","self_practice_session_time":"17:30","subscription-type":"ANNUAL","gender":"Unknown","md_remind_before_mins":15,"sgex-currency":"INR","cyw_flag":false,"sgex-cancellation-reason":"Renewed Annual Subscription","Journey status":"completed","presence_reminder":"Yes","mandala_start_dt":"2021-11-23","sgex-trial-type":"INTRODUCTORY","md_practice_time_morning":"04:30 AM","email":"kamambi96@gmail.com","md_no_of_day_completed":40,"last_name":"Amb","onboard_reason_1":"Wisdom","onboard_reason_2":"Meditation","sso_country":"IN","samyama_flag":true,"user-status":"Active","cancelled-date":1705760434000,"ex Subscription Status":"ACTIVE","monthly_satsang_flag":"Yes","user_time_zone_offset_(mins)":330,"trial-days":7,"moe_rsp_android":200,"onboard_reason_3":"Yoga","hard_bounce":false,"ssbd_my_steps":"Chew Your Food Well,Drink Water with Reverence,Don't Talk While Eating,Apply Sacred Ash,Breathe Right,Consume Honey in Warm Water","spam":false,"lom_flag":false,"last_known_city":"Madai","Email":"kamambi96@gmail.com","last_seen":1706594768000,"sso_lastname":"Amb","md_practice_time_evening":"05:30 PM","wake_up_alarm_page_alarm_enabled":"Yes","DLCD_Flag":"Yes","Days Practiced":26,"New Videos":true,"onboard_journey":"Volunteer","wake_up_alarm_page_days_selected":"Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday","My Chants Playlist":14,"kriya_reminder":"Yes","ie_flag":true,"Monthly_Meditator_Satsang":"Yes","no_of_conversions":0,"user_creation_source":"sdk","Device":"Android","pooja_reminder":"Yes","Language Preference":"ta","sso_ieo_regs_flag":false,"guestUserInstallationId":"17b3f4583-c9d741809549","install_status":true,"last_known_pincode":693020,"shoonya_flag":true,"Meditator":true,"name":"Kam","trial-status":"Expired","onboard_goal_1":"Energy","onboard_goal_3":"Space","onboard_goal_2":"conscious","subscription-date":1674312082000,"first_seen":1699538478606,"presence_reminder_time":"15min","last_known_state":"Nadu","meditation_health_reminder":"Yes","rd_flag":true,"mandala_end_dt":"1837814400000.0","sso_name":"Kam","AI-Clicked":"Yes","class_status":"","sgex-amount":900,"moengage_user_id":"654dc002bee2163","Minutes Practiced":536,"IECSO_flag":false,"sg-ex Subscription Type":"SE-Yly","onboard_age":"Between 35 and 44","goy_online_flag":false,"first_name":"Kam","Streak Day":7,"ltv":0.0,"Mobile Token":"fcm:dK-GiFKUQGG5UwQ1-kbknW:APA9z9ws3tLJPgC0W0uJs_-56Sa64Hxt2_pIioeb2b9idYhjTieAc3gGS2CgsBCdg4","wake_up_alarm_page_time_selected":"3,0","FMF_flag":true,"sso_created":"1582148415"},"event_source":"MOENGAGE","event_attributes":{"campaign_name":"30Jan-PN4","moe_campaign_tags":["engagement"],"sent_epoch_time":"1706621844","campaign_type":"GENERAL","moe_campaign_channel":"Push","moe_delivery_type":"One Time","campaign_id":"65b74b4676fadf","campaign_channel":"PUSH"},"event_uuid":"ef9051db-42dd-851ba44b","event_time":1706621846,"device_attributes":{"moengage_device_id":"66a75e4a-d104e3935f56"}},"export_day":"2024-01-30"}
```

The structure is not static, it is dynamic and keeps changing for every record.

Could you help me in splitting the JSON based on event.event_names and flatten the JSON and save it as CSV in S3.I don't have the unique list of event.event_names also.
I want to process 70 events from the file and my code takes about 5 hours to process them. I want to make it faster.

Comment: can you add expected output ? I don't understand weither you want a csv output or a json ouput.

Comment: I want to flatten and convert it to CSV for each event.event_name (I am interested in only 70 event_names) and save it as csv file. It is a big json file which has 5 million records and each record is a json by itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this.

You can get multiple files per `event_name` value which can coalesce as a post processing step later on.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Split Json Files").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)
inputFile = "../data/json5mfile.json"
outputDir = "../data_output/partitioned_output"

df = spark.read.json(inputFile)
df = df.withColumn("event_name_partition", F.col("event.event_name"))
df.show(n=100, truncate=False)

#------------
#Further transformations here that you want to be done.
#-----------

## As there will be multiple executors and the data will be distributed on them, they will each try to write their own file.
## So you can coalesce the file as a post-processing step later on.
df.write.partitionBy("event_name_partition").format("json").mode("overwrite").option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100000).save(outputDir)
```

Output : Files written out on the disk

```
data_output/
└── partitioned_output
    ├── event_name_partition=Received1
    │   └── part-00000-c3a58e7c-7a94-46f4-b2ac-aa21f11e6ab7.c000.json
    ├── event_name_partition=Received2
    │   └── part-00000-c3a58e7c-7a94-46f4-b2ac-aa21f11e6ab7.c000.json
    ├── event_name_partition=Received3
    │   └── part-00000-c3a58e7c-7a94-46f4-b2ac-aa21f11e6ab7.c000.json
    └── _SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I could achieve what I wanted.